# Define type in generate block and use it outside

Tags: system-verilog

I'm attempting to define a user-defined type in a generate block and then access it in the scope outside the generate block. Something like this:

```
generate
    if (SOME_PARAM == 0) begin
        typedef struct packed {
            logic [A-1:0][B-1:0] field1;
            logic [C-1:0] field2;
        } struct_id_t;
    end
    else begin
        typedef struct packed {
            logic [SOME_PARAM-1:0] other_field;
            logic [A-1:0][B-1:0] field1;
            logic [C-1:0] field2;
        } struct_id_t;
    end
endgenerate
struct_id_t some_struct_instance;
```

The last line of code triggers an error indicating that `struct_id_t` is undefined. Apparently, generate blocks create a local scope, which would explain the error.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Before discussing what I've considered/tried, I'll first say that I understand one solution to this is to place all uses of `struct_id_t` in the local scope created by the generate block. However, this would require quite a bit of code duplicated between the blocks that I'd really prefer to avoid.

Other things I've considered:

A compiler directive does not create a local scope like a generate block. Unfortunately, (System)Verilog does not have an `ifeq` compiler directive, so I don't think this will work.

I also tried to forward declare the type. Something like:

```
typedef struct struct_id_t;
generate
    if (SOME_PARAM == 0) begin
        typedef struct packed {
            logic [A-1:0][B-1:0] field1;
            logic [C-1:0] field2;
        } struct_id_t;
    end
    else begin
        typedef struct packed {
            logic [SOME_PARAM-1:0] other_field;
            logic [A-1:0][B-1:0] field1;
            logic [C-1:0] field2;
        } struct_id_t;
    end
endgenerate
struct_id_t some_struct_instance;
```

The resulting error complains about `struct_id_t` never being defined. Section 6.18 of the 1800-2012 standard explains the error:

> The actual data type definition of a forward typedef declaration shall be resolved within the same local scope or generate block.

So, the definition needs to be in the same scope.

I tried to create a label for the generate blocks that includes the parameter definition. That way I believe I could access the type hierarchically. Something along the lines of `gen_name[SOME_PARAM].struct_id_t`. But it seems that's not a valid name for a generate block.

What are my options?

Comment: A couple of questions: Does this code need to be synthesizable? If not, there are a number of approaches using classes. If you don't use your first attempted solution, how would you prevent `other_field` from being referenced? Where is `SOME_PARAM` being set from?

Comment: It does need to be synthesizable. `SOME_PARAM` is a module parameter. 2nd question: I think what you're saying here is that I define the struct with `other_field` and then only use that field in cases where `SOME_PARAM!=0`. I could do that and seems like a reasonable solution. Having a 2-bit unused field in the struct isn't ideal, but the synthesis tool should throw it out if it isn't used, so I guess my preference is mostly "aesthetic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to declare a type in a generate block this way. But, you can define a variable inside a block as the following and use it with a structural name:

```
 if (SOME_PARAM == 0) begin: def
        typedef struct packed {
            logic [A-1:0][B-1:0] field1;
            logic [C-1:0] field2;
        } struct_id_t;
    struct_id_t some_struct_instance;
    end
    else begin: def
        typedef struct packed {
            logic [SOME_PARAM-1:0] other_field;
            logic [A-1:0][B-1:0] field1;
            logic [C-1:0] field2;
        } struct_id_t;
      struct_id_t some_struct_instance;
    end

assign def.some_struct_instance = 1;
```

The other approach is to pass the type to the instance of your module (mod):

```
module top#(SOME_PARAM = 0, A=1, B=1, C=1)();
  typedef struct packed {
    logic [A-1:0][B-1:0] field1;
    logic [C-1:0] field2;
  } struct1_id_t;
  
  typedef struct packed {
    logic [SOME_PARAM-1:0] other_field;
    logic [A-1:0][B-1:0] field1;
    logic [C-1:0] field2;
  } struct2_d_t;

  mod #(.stuct_id_t(struct1_id_t)) mod1();
  mod #(.stuct_id_t(struct1_id_t)) mod2();
endmodule

module mod#(type struct_id_t = logic) ();
  struct_id_t some_struct_instance;
    // ...
endmodule
```

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized it was permissible to give the generate blocks the same name. For anyone else coming across this, the relevant part of the 1800-2012 standard is in section 27.5 Conditional generate constructs: "Because at most one of the alternative generate blocks is instantiated, it is permissible for there to be more than one block with the same name within a single conditional generate construct." Option (1) works nicely. Though I'm curious why it's possible to reference a variable from the generate block but not a type.